# Linq to entities compare datetime with milliseconds precision

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I have a specific linq to entity query that is written like the following:

```
var query = from orgs 
            in orgBaseQuery.Where(org => org.LastUpdated >= fromDate 
                                         && org.LastUpdated <= toDate)
```

The type of the `toDate` and `fromDate` are .net `DateTime` and the type of the `LastUpdated` is SQL `DateTime`. My problem is that the generated SQL query does not have the millisecond portion in it and that is causing some errors in our application. I was wondering if there is any solution to this problem without changing the data type of `LastUpdated` to `datetime2`?

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server**, then the `DATETIME` datatype has a precision of **3.33 ms** only - it's **not** accurate to the milliseconds. The only way to solve this is to use `DATETIME2(n)` instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your column in the database is [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), then you're not going to have the precision that you're looking for. It is a legacy data type. Starting with SQL Server 2008 (possibly R2), the better data type to use is [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx). It is a perfect match for the C# DateTime type, including precision.

Comment: unfortuanetly I cannot change the data type because the database behind the scene is part of a library we are using. I just noticed that Entity framework has a class called SqlFunctions  and a method called DateDiff. Not sure maybe that can help to do the date comparison

Comment: They won't help because, as krillgar mentioned, the millisecond portion of the datetime isn't stored in the database. If you need it, you have to change the database to store it.

Comment: Honestly, I would make a copy of the database, and try altering the column type. There shouldn't be anything that prevents the library from storing it into a `datetime2` column instead of a regular `datetime`, except that you'll then gain that precision. But try in another server (or make a backup first), just in case something breaks.

Comment: Actually it turned out that dates are stored with milliseconds precision in database and the mistake was in the way I was passing down the string version of fromDate and toDate to the API. I used the code below to convert the dates to string in a way to include milliseconds in them

Comment: public static string ToSearchDateTime(this DateTime? dt)
        {
            if (dt.HasValue)
            {
                return dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz");
                
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

Comment: Yes, but as Marc pointed out in the comments to your question, you're not going to have absolute precision because the `datetime` column type in SQL Server only goes down to 3.33 ms increments. I'd forgotten the exact difference between the precision, but it is still FAR more than enough to cause headaches.